# Canonical Bundle of product manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex manifolds. I want to know how to identify the canonical bundle $K_{X\times Y}$ in terms of $K_X$ and $K_Y$. As we know the canonical bundle $K_X:=\det(\Omega_X)$, $\Omega_X$ being the holomorphic cotangent bundle of $X$.

Comment: Do you know any relation between the cotangent bundles of $X$, $Y$, and $X\times Y$?

Comment: @KReiser I guess $T^*(X\times Y)=\pi_1^*(T^*X)\oplus \pi_2^*(T^*Y)$.

Comment: Great, now take the determinant - what happens?

Comment: @KReiser Now, $0\rightarrow \pi_1^*(T^*X)\rightarrow \pi_1^*(T^*X)\oplus\pi_2^*(T^*Y)\rightarrow \pi_2^*(T^*Y)\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, hence $K_{X\times Y}\cong K_X\otimes K_Y$ taking determinant. Is this correct?

Comment: I think there's a flaw in the last comment. All I have is $K_{X\times Y}\cong$ det$\pi_1^*(T^*X)\otimes$ det$\pi_2^*(T^*Y).$

Comment: @Partha yes, but you are on the right track. Determinant commutes with pullback, so you get that $K_{X\times Y} \cong \pi_1^* K_X \otimes \pi_2^* K_Y$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I see, thanks. As $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are just projections is it correct that deg$K_{X\times Y}=$ deg$\pi_1^* K_X+$deg $\pi_2^* K_Y=$deg $K_X+$ deg $K_Y$?

Comment: The degree of a line bundle is only intrinsically defined over a curve. But I think you're maybe looking for an analogous statement about Chern classes?

Comment: @TabesBridges yeah that would do too, for me the degree of any line bundle $L$ over any Kähler manifold $(X^n,\omega)$ would be $\int_X c_1(L)\wedge\omega^{n-1}$. I can see that $c_1(K_{X\times Y})=\pi_1^*c_1(K_X)+\pi_2^*c_1(K_Y).$ Is this right? Do we get something more?

Comment: I think that's exactly the statement, yes.